# Zend Navigation showing all items in menu

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I'm just not getting this; I'm using a standard XML-based Zend_Navigation impl, right out the box so-to-speak - and every page seems to have every menu option. I've tried everything  - activeOnly, renderSubMenu, renderParent but they all return my either everything or nothing. I'm assuming I'm misunderstanding, because what I want (the items in the "home" node to be visible on the "home" page etc) seems to be what I would have considered the default behaviour. If I have to start setting content to "active", why do you need to specify URL or container settings in your XML - surely Zend "knows" what is active...

As an example, using this page http://my.opera.com/spadille/blog/zend-navigation-with-xml (which is very standard), I would want all the top level nodes to be visible (Home/About/Product/COntact), but only the children of the "active" page. Is that not default behaviour?

Do I need a partial to achieve this?

Many thanks,

Mike

EDIT

Here's the XML

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <configdata>
 <nav>
    <home>
        <label>Home</label>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <module>default</module>
        <route>home</route>
    </home>
    <admin>         
        <label>Admin</label>
        <controller>admin</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <module>default</module>
        <route>admin</route>
    </admin>
            <results>           
        <label>Results</label>
        <controller>result</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <module>default</module>
        <route>results</route>
        <pages>
            <t>
            <label>Charts</label>
            <controller>result</controller>
            <action>graph</action>
            <module>default</module>
            <route>charts</route>
        </t>
        </pages>
    </results>
</nav>
    </configdata>
```

routes.ini

```
    routes.home.route = "/"
    routes.home.defaults.controller = index
    routes.home.defaults.action = index


    routes.admin.route = "/admin"
    routes.admin.defaults.controller = admin
    routes.admin.defaults.action = index

    routes.results.route = "/results"
    routes.results.defaults.controller = result
    routes.results.defaults.action = index

    routes.charts.route = "/results/charts"
    routes.charts.defaults.controller = result
    routes.charts.defaults.action = chart
```

And my bootstrap

```
    protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->_bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml','nav');


    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);

    $view->navigation($navigation);
}
```

And my view. I've tried...

```
    $this->navigation()->menu()
```

and then this; The following line hides the sub items of the Results Nav, but when you click on it you only get the Item and the sub item, not the top level too (because of maxDepth)

```
    $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(null,array("minDepth"=>0,"maxDepth"=>1,"onlyActiveBranch"=>true,"renderParents"=>true))
```

EDIT.

This gets me what I was after, but feels like a hack? Is this appropriate?

```
     <div class="top_menu">
            <?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(null,array("minDepth"=>0,"maxDepth"=>0,"onlyActiveBranch"=>1,"renderParents"=>true)) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sub_menu">
            <?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(null,array("minDepth"=>1,"maxDepth"=>4,"onlyActiveBranch"=>true,"renderParents"=>false)) ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: What type of pages are you creating? Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri or Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc

Comment: Thanks @Christian, I'm using MVC, like this... <admin>   
   <label>Admin</label>
   <controller>admin</controller>
   <action>index</action>
   <module>default</module>
   <route>admin</route>
  </admin>

Comment: have you tried without setting route? If yes, what does your admin route look like? Can you perhaps also provide your full xml config?

Comment: sure @ChristianBurger, I'll add an EDIT to the post. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Another EDIT with what I'm using as a solution. Not sure if its correct as an approach tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I suspect the "default behaviour" of Zend_Navigation is the use case where the entire menu tree is required to be rendered on every page. In this use case the menu's children will be displayed as drop downs using CSS/JS. In this scenario the "strange" behaviour you described actually makes sense.

Your use case is different in that you are using a mainmenu along with a submenu. This is similar to a topbar + sidebar implementation. In this scenario it is obviously not desirable for the entire menu tree to be rendered on every page.

To further confuse the issue it seems that renderSubmenu() has some unexpected behaviour in that it will render the root level of the menu, when an active branch has no children. Some have have reported this behaviour as a [bug](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6978). [Here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6673?focusedCommentId=31005&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-31005) you will find a comment suggesting something similar to your "hack"

So in summary, your "hack" seems to be a valid approach to make a single container render correctly for your specific use case. If you really want something more elegant, you could perhaps consider:

1. Using one of the findBy* methods to "extract" your submenu as new container as per [Example 40](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.menu)
2. Splitting the mainmenu and submenu into separate containers and manage the relationship in a piece of code somewhere
3. Extending Zend_Navigation_Container to enforce the desired behaviour
4. Using a partial